# Which method is ideal when Seeding a database with Code First Migrations?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I've seen a few different approaches to seeding databases using the AddOrUpdate method.

1.

```
    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
      new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Harry", LastName="Henderson"},
      new Person() { Id= 2, Name = "Henry", LastName="Ford"}
    );
```

2.

```
    var people = new List<Person>{
    new Person{Id= 1, Name = "Harry", LastName="Henderson"},
    new Person{Id= 2, Name = "Henry", LastName="Ford"}
};
    people.ForEach(newPerson => context.People.AddOrUpdate(alreadyExistsProperty => alreadyExistsProperty.Id, newPerson));
    context.SaveChanges();
```

Can someone please explain which is the more ideal/best practice approach. Why would you do one over the other or does it not matter at all?

Comment: Your first example looks more readable, although you are missing the check for duplicate Id's.

Answer (score 0):

Seed always runs. The second example will pop a duplicate key exception.

Comment: I understand that but what I'm asking is which is the ideal/best practice approach to seeding the database.

Comment: The one that doesn't pop an exception.